# PhalconPHP - Securing creating record in database

Tags: php, phalcon

I've got a question about how to make a safe record creating form data passed by user. Is:

```
$account = new Accounts();
$account->email = $parserData['email'];
$account->password = $parserData['password'];
$account->save();
```

safe or should I validate (or use binding somehow) every piece of data myself? I can't find answer about sql injection in creating a record in models tutorial available on phalcon's website with references.

Comment: SQL injection is prevented in the core, you should hash passwords though  and (optional) check if 'email' and 'password' are strings

Comment: @KA_lin please post it as answer so I can close the question.

Comment: wait a bit, maybe somebody else has a more detailed explenation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL injection is prevented in the core, you should hash passwords though and (optional) check if 'email' and 'password' are strings because of XSS , I opened an issue on this a while ago:
https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/2756

see also:
https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/security.html
http://phalcontip.com/discussion/24/harden-the-password-hashing
https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/crypt.html

Answer (score 0):

Phalcon uses prepared statements, so you don't need to worry about properly escaping when assigning variables.